# How to Ctrl+Alt+ Left/Right to move code block left and right by tab in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In NetBeans I can <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Left / Right</kbd> and move a code block left and right by a tab at a time. I can also press <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to move the code block up and down the rows.

In PhpStorm <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Up / Down</kbd> works to move the code block up and down but does not work if I try <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd>.

I have looked everywhere for key mapping in PhpStorm but can not find the setting. Is it possible?

Comment: `Tab` / `Shift + Tab` ? Works with selection, obviously. Sorry, I'm not familiar how NetBeans works so need some gif/video to say for sure.

Comment: Right. Tab/Shift +Tab does almost do the same thing. tab will only work if at the beginning of the line. otherwise it tabs the line at the cursor breaking the code. What is the keymap name for this?

Comment: If you make selection (e.g. whole line) -- it will indent/deindent whole block. But yes, in the middle of the line and no selection `Tab` will just insert Tab symbol. But there is dedicated action for indenting even if pressed in the middle of the string.